# Ember: wait for promise in router.willTransition hook

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I want to allow some users to enter a route and others don't.

I used [simple auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) for authentication and it will load the user data with a promise. The Problem is that `willTransition()` does not wait until my user is loaded so, it will show the index route before I can check if the user has access to it.

So in router.js I have:

```
willTransition(oldRoute, nextRoute, transition) {
    return this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:application').then(() => {
      if(this.get('user.isAdmin')) return true
      else alert('not allowed to enter')
    })
}
```

This is just an example in real I have more like `user.isCat` and cat are allowed to enter /cats and /cute routes.

I know that I can check `user.isAdmin` also in `beforeModel()` of the route but I have many other routes and permission groups, so I want to have a single place in the router to manage that.

Comment: IIRC, willTransition doesn't block on promises, which is why returning one isn't pausing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could abort the transition and retry it after the promise has been resolved.

So your example would look like this:

```
willTransition(transition) {
  if (this.get('pendingTransition.targetName') == transition.targetName) {
    this.set('pendingTransition', null);
    return true;
  }

  transition.abort();

  this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:application').then(() => {
    if (this.get('user.isAdmin')) {
      this.set('pendingTransition', transition);
      transition.retry();

    } else {
      alert('not allowed to enter')
    }
  })
}
```

See:

- [Example Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/82b87d0bb068f9f629ac61543b4ae765?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C&route=%2Ftwo)
- [Ember Guides: Preventing and Retrying Transitions](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/)

Answer (score 0):

willTransitionTo does not stop on promises. So the best way to achieve is to abort the transition in these kind of scenarios. Something like below could do the trick for you.

```
willTransition: function(transition) {
   return this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:application').then(() => {
      if(!this.get('user.isAdmin')){
         transition.abort();
      }
      if(!this.get('user.isCat')){
         transition.abort();
      }
   });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont understand: If you abort the transition inside then it will still not wait for the promise so untill the promise is pending, the transition will go on and the user can see the page